# ArcGis Connection Error using RestSharp

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin, arcgis

I'm trying to connect to ArcGis to geocode an address to a lat/long, from an Xamarin.iOS app.  I'm initiating the request using this manner:

```
var request = new RestRequest ("arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?f=pjson&text=380+New+York+Street+Redlands+CA+92373", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter ("content-type", "application/json");

var client = new RestClient("http://geocode.arcgis.com/");
var response = client.Execute (request);
var jsonOutput = response.Content;
```

However, it always returns blank, and gives me the error "Invalid Cookie Domain: geocode.arcgis.com".  Why is this error happening?  I can't figure this out...

Answer (score 1):

I have put an ArcGIS component on the Xamarin store (called [ArcGIS.PCL](https://components.xamarin.com/view/arcgis.pcl)) which demonstrates calling this operation in the sample projects if you want to try that (it's free).

I think your issue comes down to the underlying http client connection as using something like the modernhttpclient seems to prevent that error occurring.